# Opengl es point sprite max size

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am creating a point sprite texture program in opengl es 2.0

I remember reading that there is no guruntee that the gl_PointSize can have a size larger then `1`

Is this true?

If so how am I supposed to have textures which are not tiny on all devices? on my device things seem to be fine even at a point size of 40. But if I can not cound on this then I have a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I my experience any setting other than glPointSize=1 might be truly slow on some hardware. If you need sprites it's better to just draw a textured quad. You gain much more control and no size limit. To have the quad face the desired direction apply the inverse camera transformation to it. I.e. multiply it to the transform stack.

If you have trouble inverting the matrix either look up an easy algorithm (pretty much any invertation algorithm will do as the matrix is 3x3 or at most 4x4), or remember to store the inverse of every partial transformation you do too. I.e. if you rotate the cam by 45° on x-axis, rotate the inverse by -45°, etc.

Comment: Great thanks, wes probably going to do this anyway but for drawing quick and dirty sprites which I do not need mucn controll over I wanted this Point sprites option but I gues it's not important enogh to stress over it